# Arducam Errors: Bogus Huffman Table

Tags: camera, jpeg, microcontroller, wireless

I am working with an Arducam OV2640 to capture images and transmit from one microcontroller to another. I am getting inconsistent images. Occasionally they turn out ok but a large portion of the time they have a 'bogus Huffman Table'.

I am familiar with Huffman tables which has me guessing that I am losing some bytes in transmission be it from the camera to the micro-controller or from the wireless link between the micro-controllers I am using.

The only thing that has me confused is that I tested several thousand packets over the communication link between the two micros and I have a BER of zero (16 byte packets with 16 bit CRC with packet rejection and re-transmission if errors occur).

The image is also fine when I transmit it from the camera micro to my computer through UART.

Is the camera occasionally having issues? I have seen it mentioned as a problem but have no idea how this might be resolved.

Comment: What is your programming question, exactly?

Comment: Does anybody know programming tricks for getting the camera to be more reliable?

Comment: I have only questions on this question.

Comment: Do you have sequence numbers in your communication link, and are you checking them? Its good that the Bit Error Rate is zero, so the individual packets are valid, but what about dropped/missed packets?

Comment: I know we aren't dropping packets either. The way I have setup handshaking ensures that all of the packets are received.

We actually figured out exactly where the problem is. We can read from the camera flash memory and print that directly to UART to get a fine image. As soon as we store even a byte of the image on board the microcontroller we get bit errors. 

This explains how we got a BER of 0 with no dropped packets and how the image was still loading directly off the camera with no issues.  It has something to do with our micro. It may be broken but we know roughly what to do now.